# Grails data binding one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, one-to-many, cascade, all-delete-orphan

I am trying to take advantage of Grails' ability to handle data binding for a one-to-many association. I am able to successfully assigning to the relationship but removing single elements or all of them is not working.

Here is an example of what my model looks like:

```
class Location {
    Float latitude
    Float longitude
}

class Route {
    Location start
    Location stop

    static belongsTo: [courier: Courier]
}

class Courier {
    String name
    static hasMany = [pickups: Location]
}

class ScheduledCourier extends Courier {
    static hasMany = [routes: Route]

    static mapping = {
        routes(cascade: 'all-delete-orphan')
    }
}
```

When creating a new ScheduledCourier object via a website, I can pass a list of Routes to automatically bind with markup like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].latitude" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].longitude" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="routes[1].latitude" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="routes[1].longitude" value="10" />
```

This works for me just fine in my controller:

```
class CourierController {
    // Very simplistic save
    def saveScheduled = {
        def courier = new ScheduledCourier(params)
        courier.save()
    }

    // Very simplistic update
    def update = {
        def courier = Courier.get(params.id)
        courier.properties = params
        courier.save()
    }
}
```

If I use the following markup instead, I can step through the debugger and see that the routes property is now [] and the object saves fine but the records are not removed from the database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="routes" value="" />
```

In addition, if I sent markup like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].latitude" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].longitude" value="5" />
```

courier.routes will not be updated to only contain the 1 object.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

This is Grails 1.3.7...at least for now.

Wrote an integration test that reproduces this behavior:

```
public void testCourierSave() {
    def l1 = new Location(latitude: 5, longitude: 5).save(flush: true)
    def l2 = new Location(latitude: 10, longitude: 10).save(flush: true)

    def params = ["name": "Courier", "pickups[0].id": l1.id, "pickups[1].id": l2.id,
        "routes[0].start.id": l1.id, "routes[0].stop.id": l2.id,
        "routes[1].start.id": l2.id, "routes[1].stop.id": l1.id]

    def c1 = new ScheduledCourier(params).save(flush: true)

    assertEquals(2, c1.routes.size())

    params = [routes: ""]
    c1.properties = params
    c1.save(flush: true)
    c1.refresh()    // Since the Routes aren't deleted, this reloads them

    assertEquals(0, c1.routes.size())    // Fails

    assertEquals([], Route.findAllByCourier(c1))    // Fails if previous assert is removed
}
```

Comment: I'm using Grails 1.3.7. The big report you linked doesn't appear to be related. That is about querying a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: In the example code does `ScheduledCourier` extend `Courier` ? In the `update` method to you not need to fetch from the `ScheduledCourier` table?

Comment: Yes, ScheduledCourier extends Courier...forgot to type that part. In the update method, Grails will fetch the appropriate object. It's all in the same table in the schema...tablePerHierarchy: true (default value)

Comment: I wonder if the following is happening - when passing the `params [routes:""]` the framework is ignoring it as its just an empty string, similarly `<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].latitude" value="5" />` probably just updates the zeroth route entry in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the following is happening:

When passing the `params [routes:""]` the framework is ignoring it as it's just an empty string.

Similarly `<input type="hidden" name="routes[0].latitude" value="5" />` probably just updates the zeroth route entry in the collection, the others aren't deleted because all you've told it is that the latitude value of the zeroth route should be 5, not that this is should now be the only route in the collection.

To get the effect you want, you'll need to add a `routes.clear()` before binding the parameters.

To control when the state of the model is persisted to the database you can use [Spring transactionality](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#programmaticTransactions) which is available in Grails. This would allow you to revert to the original state of the object if subsequent processing failed. eg:

```
Courier.withTransaction {status ->

  // Load the courier

  //clear the existing routes

  // bind the new properties

  // perform extra processing

  //if the object is invalid, roll back the changes
  status.setRollbackOnly()

}
```

Comment: This is what I'm finding. Binding one-to-many associations is fine on creation but not so fine on updates. I was really looking for an answer that allows me to rely on data binding but I'm starting to think it's just not possible although not documented.

Comment: GORM is using Hibernate under the covers to store the associations which are just `Set`s or `List`s depending on what you chose. So the behaviour you're seeing here is exactly what you'd expect from these Java types.

Comment: The next issue now is that I have to handle this data manually which persists to the DB before I've finished processing the object. `routes.clear()` will cause the would-be orphaned objects to be removed from the DB but if further processing of the parent object produces an invalid object I would want to avoid the DB changes.

Comment: In this case I you can't use the short cut binding `c1.properties = params` and will have to do something like maintain a list of `routes` in the controller and then set it on the `Courier` when you're ready.

Comment: Updated my answer to give a better solution to controlling when/if the changes are saved to the db.

Comment: Thanks David! That's the path I'm going to take.